# Google signin api not working android studio using firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to sign in from google using firebase but it's not working and GoogleSignInResult result not giving any error.
Please check the code and tell me what's happening to my code.

```
package com.tube.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;

import com.tube.R;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private SignInButton mGoogleBtn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        mGoogleBtn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //HMM...
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); //Switch activities
                }
            }
        };


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"It's working here...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Sign In Successful...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fetchToken();
            }
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Auth went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });

    }

    /**
     * Fetches firebase token for single device testing
     */
    private void fetchToken(){
        // Get token
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                    // Log and toast
                    String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                    Log.d(TAG, msg);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

I've enabled google api and tried all method but unable to finding out bug because no error message showing runtime in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you enable Google SignIn in the Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled google SignIn from the firebase console.

Comment: Okay, Are you using real device to run your app ?

Comment: Yes, using real device to run app. I've added screen shot on the top please go through from it. and tell please is it necessary to add Project public-facing name to android studio.

Comment: Okay good, Add whole code in your question

Comment: Check it out now please.

Answer (score 0):

At first please ensure, that you have enabled Google SignIn Authentication in your Firebase Console. (Authentication --> Tab "Sign-in method")
Then check your "Web-Client-ID". Does this fit to the settings in your "google-services.json" in your Android project?

I use "implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'" in my build.gradle in my project to have a pre-default UI for the Firebase Authentication.

The following code worked for me for implementing the sign in mehtod:

```
   private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
     if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "-------------------------------------------");
                Log.i(TAG, auth.getCurrentUser().toString());
    }
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Successfully signed in
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Log.i(TAG, "logged in");

                    if (user != null) {
                        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                        String name = user.getDisplayName();
                        String email = user.getEmail();
                        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

                        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
                        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
                        // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
                        String uid = user.getUid();
                    }


                }
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK && shouldStartSignIn()) {
                    // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                    // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                    // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                    String err = Integer.toString(response.getError().getErrorCode());
                    Log.i(TAG, "no login");
                    Log.i(TAG, err);
                    startSignIn();
                }
            }
        }

  /**
     * Check if a FirebaseUser is logged in
     * @return
     */
    private boolean shouldStartSignIn() {
        return (!mainActivityViewModel.getIsSignedIn() && FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null);
    }

    /**
     * Show Login module with Firebase UI
     */
    private void startSignIn() {
        // Firebase Authentication Providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

        // Create and launch sign-in intent for Firebase Authentication
        Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        mainActivityViewModel.setIsSignedIn(true);
    }
```